# How to implement subtype in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table employees and it is divided into two sub types for different types of employees. How do I implement that in SQL statements to create a table

Comment: Please provide more information like Table schema, data etc

Comment: Entity: Employee [emp_id (PK), fName, LName, contact, address, emp_type]
sub type: Emp_sde [emp_id (pk), speciality]
Emp_supp [emp_id (pk), specification] 
these are the three tables, employee is the super type, other twos are the sub type

Comment: And what do you need to do? Create a query (for a report) showing the data from all three tables? Use outer joins. Or something else?

Comment: I'd probably keep it simple: Make this one `employee` table with the two columns `speciality`and `specification` added plus a check constraint on `((emp_type = 'SDE' and speciality is not null and specification is null) or (emp_type = 'SUPP' and speciality is null and specification is not null))`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Object-Derived tables then you only need a single table (and can insert inherited types into it):

```sql
CREATE TYPE Employee AS OBJECT (
  emp_id   INT,
  fName    VARCHAR2(20),
  LName    VARCHAR2(20),
  contact  VARCHAR2(20),
  address  VARCHAR2(20),
  emp_type VARCHAR2(20)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE Emp_SDE UNDER Employee (
  speciality VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TYPE Emp_supp UNDER Employee (
  specification VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE employees OF Employee (
  emp_id PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then you can insert the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (
  Employee(1, 'Alice', 'Abbot', NULL, '123 Somewhere', 'Basic Emp')
);

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (
  Emp_SDE(2, 'Betty', 'Baron', NULL, '456 Other Place', 'SDE Emp', 'My Speciality')
);

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (
  Emp_Supp(3, 'Carol', 'Cray', NULL, '789 Elsewhere', 'Supp Emp', 'My Specification')
);
```

Then if you query the table:

```sql
SELECT e.*,
       TREAT(VALUE(e) AS Emp_SDE).speciality AS speciality,
       TREAT(VALUE(e) AS Emp_Supp).specification AS specification
FROM   Employees e;
```

The output is:

> | EMP_ID | FNAME | LNAME | CONTACT | ADDRESS | EMP_TYPE | SPECIALITY | SPECIFICATION |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alice | Abbot |  | 123 Somewhere | Basic Emp |  |  |
> | 2 | Betty | Baron |  | 456 Other Place | SDE Emp | My Speciality |  |
> | 3 | Carol | Cray |  | 789 Elsewhere | Supp Emp |  | My Specification |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fda832bcc80d2fe20988d22e92a345fa)*

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Like we user DROP TABLE command, is there any command to delete objects like one we created. What if I want to delete Employee?

Comment: @Somil `DROP TABLE Employees;`, `DROP TYPE Emp_supp;`, `DROP TYPE Emp_SDE;` then `DROP TYPE Employee;` (you need to drop all the inherited tables/types before you drop the super-type.)

Comment: This is fine for Oracle, but this is not SQL (it uses Oracle-specific, non-SQL features), and the Subtypes do not have integrity.  Whereas SQL provides Subtypes, and in a much simpler way.  Granted Oracle is not SQL compliant in many instances, this is just one such.  Please remove the `sql` tag, so that it does not confuse those seeking an SQL solution.

Comment: This is SQL of the Oracle dialect; almost no database implements only the ANSI SQL specification, they all add unique features.